# Error while adding tags to vm with powershell after reading from csv

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, tags, virtual-machine

I am trying to add tags to azure vm by reading from csv file with a powershell script. I want to read the value via loop and add to existing tags of vm, if any. Below is my code and the respective errors.

$data = Import-CSV C:\Documents\tags-vms.csv

```
foreach($info in $data){

$tags =  (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName policyResourceGroup -Name $info.psobject.properties.value[0]).Tags

$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('@{$info.Tags}')

$newtags = (& $scriptBlock)

$tags += $newtags 
Write-Host $tags
}


Now the error is 

Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:1 char:13
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2145247Z + @{$info.Tags}
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2147301Z +             ~
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2149246Z Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2152282Z At line:1 char:13
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2154454Z + @{$info.Tags}
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2156590Z +             ~
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2166796Z The hash literal was incomplete."
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2168854Z At C:\agent\_work\_temp\e8ee61c2-c3f4-4ea5-99ac-4feb671fff57.ps1:18 char:1
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2169842Z + $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('@{$info.Tags}')
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2170521Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2171329Z     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
2021-12-20T16:01:09.2171826Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException



Can someone please help.



**csv file contains**

VmName       Tags
test-vm01   "loc"="us"
test-vm02   "Loc"="Us";"doseage"="Second"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue lies in this line and how you're retrieving the tag info from the CSV object from your foreach loop:

```
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('@{$info.Tags}')
```

In the previous line in your script, to define the $tags variable, you retrieve the value of the name of the VM in the CSV object using ($info.psobject.properties.value[0]). I would attempt to use that same format in the next line, but modifying it to retrieve the tag part of the CSV object using the index of 1:

So instead of:

```
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('@{$info.Tags}')
```

use:

```
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create('@{$info.psobject.properties.value[1]}')
```

Comment: Hi JGoose, followed your suggestion. But I am getting the same error.



Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:1 char:37
2021-12-21T07:21:55.3231637Z + @{$info.psobject.properties.value[1]}
2021-12-21T07:21:55.3233791Z +                                     ~
2021-12-21T07:21:55.3255793Z Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.